# constexpr: saving calculation results

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to save the input and output of `constexpr` function during build?

I.e. I would like to have as output of the build a file which contains triplets: `func, input, output` for each evaluation of `const` expression function.

I am using g++ 4 on a `Linux` machine for the build.

Comment: I don't know of any tool/compiler flag which does this but perhaps you can modify the tool demonstrated here for [template meta-programs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0bzwHBiNc4).

Comment: 10x, i will check it. seems more template-oriented than constexpr.